# How do I reroute a GET request from my root in app.js to a route in my controllers folder in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm basically trying to recreate this from Sinatra in Express:

```
get '/' do
 redirect '/channels'
end
```

I'm trying to build a Node.js/Express.js app and am starting to incorporate an MVC structure. My `app.js` file contains my `/` route, as such:

**app.js**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/search');
 })
```

I want it to redirect to the `/search` route in `controllers/search.js`, which contains the following:

**controllers/search.js**

```
const express = require('express');  
const app = express();


app.get('/search', function(req, res) {    
 res.render('index.js'); 
})
```

The browser does redirect to `localhost:3000/search` but it displays `Cannot GET /search`. All of the tutorials and documentation I see about rerouting in Express don't show the whole file so I'm not able to tell if I have to `require` or `export` anything ala Node.js.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I often choose another approach. But what you said looks like `mountpath` can help:
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.mountpath

Comment: make sure to import your search file and it will be available in your app.js. Rajats pattern should give you an idea of how to go about this. You can have your router that imports other routers in another file all subsequent routers just need to be imported in to that file before being used.

Comment: So I have to import it simply because app.js will say, "I have no idea what '/search' is"? And it now knows what it is because we required it and search.js exported it? I'm familiar with Node.js having to require/export things but didn't comprehend that with routes, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var searchRouter = require('./searchRouter');
var app = express();

app.use('/', searchRouter);

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
```

searchRouter.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Nope, try /search');
});

router.get('/search', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('yeah!! you found me');
});

module.exports = router;
```

you can extend this logic by

```
app.use('/search', searchRouter);
```

in search router

```
// this handles /search
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {}

//this handles /search/apple
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {}
```

Comment: So before I saw your response, I did something similar and I am now hitting the route. Let me see if I am understanding this correctly. For server.js to be able to the reroute, it must require searchRouter.js which is exporting router (which handles the GET request with the logic we put in it)?

Comment: correct. In server.js we tell the express router that for all '/' requests do 'this' before you proceed . read middleware https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

inside the middleware we setup the actual routes\controllers as you prefer. Middlewares are extremely powerful to do stuff on your request before they are handled.